# Git always turned on even after creating new project

Tags: android

I have an issue with Android Studio. Once I enabled Git in my IDE it's always turned on even when i'm creating new project. After creating new project it's just automatically merging with my last created repository. But when i saw some tutorials people always enable them after creating a new project. How can i make this working like that? Or it's normal that my Git always enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating the new project in a folder that already has a git repository. If you have a folder `projects`, you should create `projects/app1` and `projects/app2` each with their own git repo. Don't create a git repo in `projects` itself.

To find out if a folder has a git repo already, you should start Git Bash (on Windows) or Terminal (on Mac/Linux). Then `cd` to the folder and then type `ls -a`. If you see a subfolder named `.git`, then that folder has a git repo.

Since you are just beginning, you can probably just delete the `.git` folder and start over.

WARNING: Deleting `.git` will remove all history of commits. Do not do this if you have an on-going project that contains commits.

Comment: You are right. If i will delete this .git right now what will happen? I will just unbind this subfoled? P.S. it doesn't helped me. What can i do to solve it?

Comment: @Dante313 If you delete the `.git` folder, you are deleting the git repo. So if you have made any commits, you will lose the history of your work. If there is no history, or you don't care about losing the history, then you can delete `.git` safely. It only affects that parent directory.

Comment: tbh i don't really have history. I'm just used Git for practice how it work. So i will delete it and recreate. Thank you!